# Lucky to Vs. Lucky to be

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is there any difference in term of emphasis between:

> 1. "I consider myself extraordinarily lucky **to be working** with you"
> 2. "I consider myself extraordinarily lucky **to work** with you"

Comment: Luck has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

The first sounds as if working with this person(s) is a new(ish) thing. The second implies it has been ongoing for some period of time.

Comment: general statement re the fact versus emphasis on the fact.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence implies that it is a special occasion to be working with someone you do not normally work with.The second one; however, suggests that you are thankful that they, often, work with you.